# Issues getting dual sim network info in Jelly Bean (Android 4.2)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am new to Android Development. I am trying to create an application that needs to display network information. Its aim it get `dual sim network` info for my Android 6.0 device, but I can't get dual sim network info in with Jelly Bean (Android 4.2).

```
     private void GetDeviceImIeBySlot(int simSlotNum)
    {
        TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);

        Class telephonyClass = Class.ForName(telemamanger.Class.Name);
        //Java.Lang.Reflect.Method[] methods = telephonyClass.GetMethods();

        Class[] parameter = new Class[1];

        parameter[0] = Java.Lang.Integer.Type;
        Java.Lang.Reflect.Method getSimID = telephonyClass.GetMethod("SimOperatorName", parameter);

        Java.Lang.Object[] obParameter = new Java.Lang.Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = simSlotNum;
        Java.Lang.Object ob_phone = getSimID.Invoke(telemamanger, obParameter);
        string imsi2 = ob_phone.ToString();
       // MessageBoxAndroid.Show(this, "this is " + imsi2);
    }
```

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how can you make it work with Android 6.0 device, I used Android 6.0, 4.4 and 4.2 emulators to test your code, all crashed with error:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodException: SimOperatorName [int]

in the code line: `Java.Lang.Reflect.Method getSimID = telephonyClass.GetMethod("SimOperatorName", parameter);`

Just looked at your code, I assume that you want to get the MCC+MNC (mobile country code + mobile network code) of the provider of the SIM, then you can simply code like this:

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
var simoperator = telemamanger.SimOperator;
```

There are many other properties may be useful for your case, for example:

```
var simoperatorName = telemamanger.SimOperatorName;
var simserialNumber = telemamanger.SimSerialNumber;
var netoperator = telemamanger.NetworkOperator;
var netoperatorName = telemamanger.NetworkOperatorName;
var nettype = telemamanger.NetworkType;
```

You can find them and some other properties, methods and fields in [TelephonyManager Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager/).